# CLLocationCoordinate2D does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift, casting, core-location, nsnotificationcenter

My singleton location manager posts a notification whenever new location data is retrieved inside `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`:

```
...
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LocationUpdate", object: self, userInfo: ["currentLocation": currentLocation,
                                                                                                      "currentLocationPoints": currentLocationPoints])`
...
```

With the above notification posting, I'm getting the following errors for the `userInfo` section:

```
Value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D! does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'`
```

Therefore I made the following type casting:

```
userInfo: ["currentLocation": currentLocation as! AnyObject,
           "currentLocationPoints": currentLocationPoints as! AnyObject]
```

And this time I'm getting the following error during runtime:

```
Could not cast value of type '__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D' (0xbb1f0) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x312d074).
```

Why is the casting failing? I know the difference between `Any` and `AnyObject` that `AnyObject` can't be an enum or such but `CLLocationCoordinate2D` should be fine for casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a `struct` and does not conform to the `AnyObject` protocol. Therefore it cannot be stored into a dictionary.

A possible solution is to post the `Double` values of `latitude` and `longitude` separately.

Another solution is to link to `MapKit.framework` and use an extension of `NSValue` (which conforms to `AnyObject`)

set:

```
let value = NSValue(MKCoordinate: currentLocation)
dictionary["currentLocation"] = value
```

get:

```
let value = dictionary["currentLocation"] as! NSValue
let currentLocation = value.MKCoordinateValue
```